# React JS - Arrow function Showing error in compiling

Tags: reactjs

Iam getting errors on simple arrow functions

Not much Done as I was not able to understand the error

```
   onChange = (event) => {
            ^
   this.setState({
         [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
```

}
It should not show error

Comment: Uh, are you using babel?

Comment: Would you mind telling what the error message says? Also, the caret is pointing at the assignment operator, not the arrow function, so it's possible that it has nothing to do with the arrow function.

Comment: The error is something like
Syntax Error: Unexpected token (16:18)
Module build failed: SyntaxError: E:/Xampp/htdocs/treatment/resources/js/components/auth/Login.js: Unexpected token (15:13)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like this is issue with class property rather than arrow function. 
You need to use `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` if using babel
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties